# Determine projection system

Tags: coordinate-system

I have standalone program that based on geodata generates zone coordinates. I dont know what projection system is used but I have a lot of example data. All of them are in Poland i.e.

lon lat lon1 lat1

1. 19,112476   50,259939   508 266
2. 17,02595    51,08383    356 357
3. 19,902374   50,007719   563 238
4. 19,948689   49,838334   566 219
5. 19,00879444 50,101288   501 248
6. 18,793566   50,321204   487 273
7. 19,133759   50,256733   510 266
8. 19,039863   50,281821   503 269
9. 18,976984   49,829918   498 218
10. 18,435098   50,055016   463 243
11. 19,375353   51,345391   527 386
12. 21,53695    53,068261   672 579
13. 19,523826   51,741878   537 430
14. 19,450966   51,711538   532 427
15. 18,65008    51,598973   477 414
16. 22,559479   51,211099   748 371
17. 20,519703   53,77942    603 658
18. 23,08975    53,15784    788 589
19. 20,816318   52,402991   624 505
20. 20,899545   52,289099   629 493

I recognize that system is similar to polish cs92 ( one to one kilometer web) but calculations works mainly for Warsaw ( 21E ) other localalization generates some differences
Anyone has idea how to recognize what system is used in program ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  To use the advice in the duplicate you may have to create a shapefile from your X,Y coordinates first.

Comment: You can use the Identify tool to help figure this out. When you click on a point with this tool, QGIS calculates coordinates in the project CRS (derived attributes > clicked coordinate x and clicked coordinate y). So make a reasonable guess at the CRS, change the project to that CRS, and click on a point. Try it with different CRS's until you find the one where the clicked coordinate values match up (approximately) with the calculated ones.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of this "standalone program?" It might be worth reading through the code to see if you can figure it out (best case scenario, the programmer wrote a comment like `#convert point coordinates from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:5639`).